# Plot text is lost when importing matplotlib images to Microsoft Word 2013

Tags: python, matplotlib, ms-word, eps

I am using `matplotlib 1.4.3`  on `python 2.7` and am saving my plots as ".eps" files on my linux server.

For my research paper, I need to include these images into `MS Word 2013` where the text of my research lies. However, when I import the image into MS word, all the text from the plot is lost e.g. axis labels, tick labels, legends. Only the non-text parts of the image show up.

I searched multiple forums

I have tried converting the `.eps` file to `.emf` format as well using https://cloudconvert.com/eps-to-emf and few other similar services, but the issue with this process is that the font of my text changes. I have also used `Inkscape 0.91`for converting `.eps` to `.emf` and there also the quality is not good (the font changes, the grey shades become shades of red) and I am not able to replicate the exact style as was there in `.eps` file.

Has anyone been able to solve this, issue ?

Comment: Do you need them to be eps format? Can you use pdf?

Comment: Can PDF be inserted as an image?

Comment: I tried embedding PDF as an adobe acrobat PDF object. But when I convert my document to PDF then I see a very blurry image of the plot which is much worse than using high resolution png.

Comment: I've never used Word2013, but in Word2011 on a mac, if I drag and drop a .pdf it looks fine. How did you make the pdf? (i.e. did you save as pdf from `matplotlib`)?

Comment: If you need vector images, you may have more luck with svg (either directly or via visio, inkscape or a very recent libreoffice). But it is still very much hit and miss (and more hit than miss). Office was designed for bitmap images, with visio/adobe files formats bolted on. Microsoft interest for open vector formats is recent and due to its internet explorer debacle. And since there were no users for its vector formats until recently, I'm not sure that what matplotlib produces actually works in other apps.

Answer (score 0):

What seems to work is that I save as .png, then import in Powerpoint, select and copy it and finally paste special in Word as .jpeg or .gif